# Issue finding a syntax error - Not sure if it has to do with Visual Code

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm getting a ton of syntax errors on some C code I wrote and I wasn't sure why. I decided to try recreating a project I had stored on replit and it wouldn't run correctly. I'm not entirely sure why.

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
// Macros
// Definitions
// Structs
typedef struct Notecard {
    char* topic;
    char* question;
    char* answer;
}Notecard;

typedef struct List {
    Notecard* list;
    int length;
    int capacity;
    void (*insert) (List* list, struct Notecard value);
}List;

typedef struct Node {
    Notecard card;
    Node* next;
}Node;

typedef struct LinkedList {
    Node* head;
    void (*append) (LinkedList* linked, Node n);
    void (*printList) (LinkedList* linked);
}LinkedList;

// Function Declarations
void insertion(List* arr, Notecard value);
void append(LinkedList linked, Node n);
void printList(LinkedList linked);


#endif // !HEADER_H
```

The first error out of a giant list it is giving me is sayingf that "void (*insert) (List* list,.. ect requires a semicolon after the List*. Is this an issue with Vs?

Comment: At the time `void (*insert) (List* list, struct Notecard value)` is encountered by the compiler. there is no `List` type, there is only `struct List` (and you're in it). A C++ compiler will eat this, a C compiler will not.

Comment: The first thing you need to memorise when learning a new language is the name of the language. C is not C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List*` is not defined yet since u r still inside its definition when the line `void (*insert) (List* list, struct Notecard value);` is executed.Therefore, `List* list` will not work.

You have to still put `struct List* list` there to make it work.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize it wasn't defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I compiled your code and below is how it should be

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
// Macros
// Definitions
// Structs
typedef struct Notecard {
    char* topic;
    char* question;
    char* answer;
}Notecard;

typedef struct List {
    Notecard* list;
    int length;
    int capacity;
    void (*insert) (struct List* list, struct Notecard value);
}List;

typedef struct Node {
    Notecard card;
    struct ode* next;
}Node;

typedef struct LinkedList {
    Node* head;
    void (*append) (struct LinkedList* linked, Node n);
    void (*printList) (struct LinkedList* linked);
}LinkedList;

// Function Declarations
void insertion(List* arr, Notecard value);
void append(LinkedList linked, Node n);
void printList(LinkedList linked);


#endif // !HEADER_H
```